How can I use an electric hand planer to create a crown on a redwood 2x6?
I want to create a crown on a deck top railing to shed water. Is there a way i could use a hand planer with some type of jig to accomplish this? I want the 2x6 to be higher down the center line like a gable roof. I want to do it in place without removing it.

A plane, electric or a hand plane, will only get but so close to the post, unless it is a top mounted cap and not cut between the posts

A line(chalk) down the centre where you want the high point to be and maybe two lines down the sides where you want the low point.  Take small cuts.

There are planes with concave base (e.g., https://kakuritools.com/products/kakuri-ebony-mini-plane-no-3-chamferinground-18), but, as mentioned above, you'd need to file the last few cm. by hand.

My first thought was "add something on top that already has the right profile". But the catch is you have redwood right now and the reasonably priced things to do that would not match at all - either bare light wood or wood that comes already primed white or composite or plastic also generally supplied white. All of which works great for trim to be painted in a typical room but doesn't match a redwood deck.

Depending on the planer, you might be able to attach a fence with a pivot, eg https://www.amazon.com/Bosch-2607001077-Bevel-Fence-Planers/dp/B0009H5O50

Hand planes have been used to do this since they were first invented... Mark the high point and the low points and use a straight edge, or make a template.

Problem: Deck top railings almost always have nails and/or screws in them to hold them down to the deck. Planes don't plane through nails and screws. Unless your deck top railing was entirely glued onto the deck, you'll rather quickly ruin the blades the first nail/screw you hit.
Frame challenge: Remove the deck top railing from the deck. Carefully remove all nails/screws. Then you can either:

Use the plane per Crip659's and Solar Mike's comments above: mark the centerline of the top surface and bottom edge of the desired slope on the sides and start planing.
Use a table saw with the blade beveled out away from the fence at the desired angle, and make the angled cuts on the deck top railing in one pass.

Then mount the railing back on the deck.

My top railing is held with screws from underneath: 2 advantages 1) the top can be planed with no issue, 2) no screw or nails to mar the surface and allow water to penetrate.

I'd check how long the screws are (hopefully the installers didn't mix lengths) and how close they are to the edge. If 100% centered, then an in-place cut or planing might work.

If you make the top fully convex (round) it will be painful to lean on.
Making it as you say, like a gable roof, would be better but still painful to lean on the apex so make it asymmetrical with a larger surface towards the deck for leaning.  Rather than a plane, just run it through a table saw twice with the blade angle and fence set to create the two  beveled edges, then sand down the apex a little by hand.
Continuing that direction ... why not leave it flat and install the whole thing at an angle leaning down towards the deck?  That's quite common, easy, looks fine, is most comfortable to lean on, and if the angle isn't too great, still allows people to put things on top whereas any kind of crowned surface would make that impossible.
